# Amplify Headless Init failing to set up environment - trying to use aws/credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, github-actions

I'm trying to do a headless init of amplify through github actions but it appears that the init is looking for credentials in /home/runner/.aws/credentials instead of using the ones I provide via env. Am I misinterpreting the error?

Github Action:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Set up AWS Amplify
      run: sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
    - name: Amplify headless init
      run: sh ./headless_init_env.sh
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    - name: Amplify headless publish
      run: sh ./amplify/deployment/headless_publish.sh
```

headless_publish.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'

AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"project\",\
\"useProfile\":false,\
\"accessKeyId\":\"${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}\",\
\"secretAccessKey\":\"${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}\",\
\"region\":\"us-east-2\"\
}"

AWSFRONTENDCONFIG="{\
\"SourceDir\": \"src\",\
\"DistributionDir\": \"dist\",\
\"BuildCommand\": \"npm run build\",\
\"StartCommand\": \"npm run serve\"\
}"

AMPLIFY="{\
\"projectName\":\"character-corner\",\
\"envName\":\"prod\",\
\"defaultEditor\":\"code\"\
}"
PROVIDERS="{\
\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG\
}"
FRONTEND="{\
\"framework\":\"vue\",\
\"config\":$AWSFRONTENDCONFIG\
}"

amplify init \
--amplify $AMPLIFY \
--providers $PROVIDERS \
--frontend $FRONTEND \
--yes
```

But I run in to this error:

```
- Initializing your environment: prod
✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
init failed
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/.aws/credentials'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Proxy.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
    at IniLoader.parseFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:47)
    at IniLoader.loadFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:56:30)
    at Config.region (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:100:36)
    at Config.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:507:39)
    at Config.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:342:12)
    at Config.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:507:32)
    at new Config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:341:19) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/runner/.aws/credentials'
}
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It looks like AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG is bypassing the provided credentials and trying to set up an environment with creds in a file that doesn't exist.

I did a manual touch of the /home/runner/.aws/credentials and config files and the script progresses but everything fails. I get the feeling that this is a no-no.

```
ResourceNotReady: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
    at constructor.setError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/resource_waiter.js:182:47)
    at Request.CHECK_ACCEPTORS (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/resource_waiter.js:44:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12) {
  message: 'Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete',
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the [`amplify-cli-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/amplify-cli-action) rather than inventing your own